# The npm version does not change when I change the node version with the n library

Tags: node.js, npm, n

I want my `npm` version to match my `node` version but no matter what `node` version I change it to with the n library the npm version is always 8.19.2. I am on a MAC running Monterey.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have more than one version of npm installed and in your `PATH`, and the version that `n` is updating is not the first npm found.

Where is the active npm installed? The default location that `n` installs to is:

```
$ command -v npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

If your OS has `which`, you can see all the locations at once (I just have one installed):

```
$ which -a npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
```

Comment: I have `prefix=/Users/jisay93/.npm` in my `.npmrc` file in order to avoid using sudo with npm. `which -a npm` gives me
`/usr/local/bin/npm
/Users/jisay93/.n/bin/npm`
I think `n` is changing the npm at `/Users/jisay93/.n/bin/npm` but when I run npm it is running the other npm. I have tried `sudo npm uninstall npm` but depending on which terminal window I run it in I either get an error or it completes but still shows npm at `usr/local/bin/npm`. I should have said I am on a mac.

Comment: It looks like the issue was Webstorm placed a npm alias in `user/local/bin/npm`. I deleted it and now `which -a npm` only shows the `n` library version. I would not have found this without your help. Thanks!